# JSON is not nested in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a several models in a heirarchy, 1:many at each level. Each class is associated only with the class above it and the one below it, ie:

L1 course,
L2 unit,
L3 unit layout,
L4 layout fields,
L5 table fields (not in code, but a sibling of layout fields)

I am trying to build a JSON response of the entire hierarchy.

```
def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json do
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
        @units = @course.units.all
        @unit_layouts = UnitLayout.where(:unit_id => @units)
        @layout_fields = LayoutField.where(:unit_layout_id => @unit_layouts)
        response = {:course => @course, :units => @units, :unit_layouts => @unit_layouts, :layout_fields => @layout_fields}
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json {render :json => response }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The code is bring back the correct values, but the units, unit_layouts and layout_fields are all nested at the same level under course. I would like them to be nested inside their parent.

Comment: This is because you're building them with each collection at the top level. That's what the line `response = {:course => @course, :units => @units, :unit_layouts => @unit_layouts, :layout_fields => @layout_fields}` does.

Comment: You also shouldn't be nesting two `respond_to` blocks.

Comment: You *also* shouldn't be re-finding the course inside your `format :json` block. You already found it up above, you only need the line `@course = Course.find(params[:id])` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) with `:include` to include the associated records.

Here's a stab at it:

```
@course = Course.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json do
    render :json => @course.to_json(:include => { :units => { :include => :layouts } })
  end
end
```

It's probably not 100% correct, because you haven't included all the names of your associations, but I'm assuming that `Unit` has_many `Layouts`. To include the deeper nesting, add additional nested `:include`s.

Comment: Hi ***meagar*** that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much for your time & multiple posts. It works perfectly.