# Both peer models not appearing in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

This is a follow-up to this question: [JSON is not nested in rails view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078461/json-is-not-nested-in-rails-view/13078589#13078589)

I have an application that has a heirarchy of models, each 1:many as they descend. At the second from bottom level is a model called **LessonLayout** and it has two children, with a 0:many relationship possible. The children are called **LayoutField** and **LayoutTable**.

So far I have this code listed below (with the help of SO user **meagar**).

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json do
      render :json => @course.to_json(:include => { :units => { :include => {:lessons => {:include => { :lesson_layouts => { :include => :layout_fields, :include => :layout_tables}}}}}})
    end
  end
end
```

A lesson layout with have either a **:layout_fields** or **:layout_tables** object. At present it produces the **:layout_tables** data, but does not display the **:layout_fields**. If I reverse the objects in the ruby code, the converse happens. I would like to see both returned in the JSON.

I've tried playing around with the code but am not getting anywhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. Pass the two peer objects in an array, like this:

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json do
      render :json => @course.to_json(:include => { :units => { :include => {:lessons => {:include => { :lesson_layouts => { :include => [:layout_fields, :layout_tables]}}}}})
    end
  end
end
```